Poincaré duality and Mayer–Vietoris sequence
In his article, Davis states that if a $n$-dimensional Poincaré duality group $G$ splits along a subgroup $C$ then the cohomological dimension of $C$ must be $n-1$. I am struggling to understand why this must be the case. The idea is to use Mayer–Vietoris sequence. Suppose $\operatorname{cd}(C)<n-1$. I could only get as far as concluding that  $H_{n}(G)\simeq H_{n}(A)\oplus H_{n}(B)$. But I don't see how this leads to a contradiction.
I would greatly appreciate any help with regards to this.

What article do you mean to link?  Your link does not resolve.

Do you know how to prove that an  infinite index subgroup of a PD(n) group has $cd<n$?

The result that @MoisheKohan refers to is sometimes called Strebel's theorem. See R. Strebel. A remark on subgroups of infinite index in Poincaré duality groups. Comment. Math. Helv., 52(3):317–324, 1977.

If I remember correctly, it is also in Ken Brown's book.

@LSpice It should open now.

$\DeclareMathOperator\PD{PD}\DeclareMathOperator\cd{cd}$You need two ingredients which Davis assumes the reader is aware of:

Strebel's theorem: If $G$ is a $\PD(n)$ group, then every infinite index subgroup $H< G$ satisfies $\cd(H)<n$. Ken Brown in his book "Cohomology of groups" gives this theorem as an exercise with a detailed  hint (chapter 8, section 10). You can also read the original Strebel's paper "A remark on subgroups of infinite index in Poincaré duality groups".

Suppose that a group $G$ admits a nontrivial graph of groups decomposition. Then every vertex group of this decomposition has infinite index in $G$. This is an easy consequence of Bass–Serre theory of group actions on trees (if a finite index subgroup in $G$ has a fixed vertex in the Bass–Serre tree $T$, then $G$ has a finite orbit in $T$, hence, has a fixed vertex in $T$, contradicting nontriviality of the graph of groups).


Now, combine these two facts with the MV sequence; you will see that  if $G=A*_C B$ is a nontrivial amalgam, and $\cd(C)<n-1$ and $G$ is a $\PD(n)$ group, then for every $\mathbb ZG$-module $M$ we have $H^n(G, M)=0$, which is a contradiction with the assumption that $G$ is a $\PD(n)$ group.

Ah, of course. I confused myself by applying the theorem to $C$ instead of to $A$ and $B$.

That settles it. Thank you!
